# Applescript process name `Can’t get name of "login".`

Tags: process, applescript

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script ""
    set processList to processes of window 1
    repeat with p in processList
        set n to name of p
    end repeat
    activate
end tell
```

trying to get the process's name and it's failing help please

Comment: `processes` is already a list of names (text).

Comment: @red_menace yeah I figured that out 3 hours later it was a string not a list. the string has no separators so you can't easily see the real processes. anyways I don't need it anymore cause I re-did my start terminal script completely to avoid a bug of duplicate windows. by launching terminal first

Answer (score 0):

This will give you both the processes and names of each **Terminal**  window.

```
set processList to {}
set windowNames to {}

tell application "Terminal"
    set theWindows to windows
    repeat with i from 1 to count of theWindows
        set thisItem to window i's id
        tell window id thisItem
            set {end of processList, end of windowNames} ¬
                to {processes, name}
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: I wanted it per window not per application? does this also work per window?

Comment: This code only targets windows in Terminal